# Using physical device with Android Studio to send data to SQL Server

Tags: android, sql

I have created an Android App with the Android Studio IDE. I have done all the codes, everything seems to be ok, but I get error every time I try to send to SQL Server. I know I am very close to figuring it out, and I know it has something to do with the IP address. I have enabled all the Protocols for SQL Server.
I've disabled the Windows Firewall.
Anti-virus is not the issue.
I am very confused on which IP Address to use for communication to work properly. Both Computer and Tablet are connected to my iPhone Hotspot network.

```
  try
                {
                    Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

                    String username = "sa";
                    String password = "patrickdorian";
                    String gender = "";

                    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

                    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

                    Connection DbConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.137.166:1433/Android DB;"+"encrypt=false;user="+username+";password"+password);
```

[Here][1]

Here is the error when I try to send the data to SQL Server[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3hID.jpg

Comment: JDBC is not designed for use by mobile devices, from a security and reliability standpoint. Please use something else, such as having your app talk to a Web service, that in turn talks to a local database.

Comment: OK, thank you. Do you have any resource I can use for this. I have noticed that using the jtds driver works with the built-in emulator and third party emulators.

Comment: I use JDBC with a remote database for university purpose and it works like a charm. The only thing that comes in my mind could be the ip. When I used a localhost database with Flutter I needed to put 10.0.0.1 as IP or something like that for my phone testing. So it could be the same for Java. Need some documentation about it. Of course you don't have problem with an emulator, but just phisycal devices.

Comment: "Do you have any resource I can use for this" -- Web services have been around for about two decades, longer than Android itself has been around. The details of setting up a Web service will vary by platform, and you would need to determine what the options are for a Windows server. On the Android app side, there are libraries for accessing Web services, such as Retrofit for talking to a REST-style Web service.

Comment: @StefanoLeone: "I use JDBC with a remote database for university purpose and it works like a charm" -- how are you securing the database credentials? How are you encrypting the network traffic? How are you handling when the device switches between mobile data and WiFi? How are you handling when the device loses connectivity for a longer period of time?

Comment: @CommonsWare Man, it's just an application for education purpose, I'm the only one having that application... Of course for official application I would use a backend system like NodeJs or PHP...

Comment: @CommonsWare "Web services have been around for two for about two decades"-- I'm yet to treat web services because I'm new in programming that's why I was asking if there is a resource that I can use for my app. Thank you.

Comment: @StefanoLeone "I use JDBC with a remote database" -- Yes, just for university purposes. I would appreciate any documentation you have that can help me with this. Thanks